# Using 2 where clauses with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 database tables the first table, called `LinkAnalysis`, has a primary key of `LinkID` and has a field, named `LinkAnalysisCreator`, where, using C# I capture the logged on user as the creator of the record.

In another table, named Subjects, I have `LinkID` as a foreign key with `subjectID` as a primary key.

I need to write a query to compare the logged on user to the `LinkAnalysisCreator` and the subject ID.  Both these parameters are passed to a method in a C# class

I have this C# query

```
using (var context = new CADWEntities())
{
    var ownercheck = context.LinkAnalysis.Where(s => s.LinkAnalysisCreator == dbUser) &&
                     (context.Subjects.Where(c=> c.SubjectId == SubjectID));
    totalRowCount = ownercheck.Count();
    if (totalRowCount == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I cannot get this to compile the error message is:
Operator `&&` cannot be applied to operands of type `System.Linq.IQueryable<LinkAnalysis2.LinkAnalysi>` and `System.Linq.IQueryable<LinkAnalysis2.Subject>`

I have search for a solution but have not been able to find any example of a multi where statement against different tables.  I viewed hours of videos on PluralSight but none of them addresses a situation where they use more then 1 `where` clause.

This seems like such a simple task but has proven very difficult to figure out.  Any help would be appreciated.

The query works fine if I use only 1 of the where clauses, but that is not what I need.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get a list with 2 different entities? I guess Subjects and LinkAnalysis isn't the same type to begin with?

Comment: What type of entity are you expecting `ownercheck` to be? If you want to limit a query based on two different tables' values, I suspect you want to JOIN them, then apply the WHERE filters to the result.

Comment: when you actually want the 2 seperate where clauses (without any joins, which could be done using basic LINQ or navigation properties in method syntax), why don't you just combine them with another .Where() call - just skip the &&?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate something based on your code with both your data and some example data so you can test it live.

Using Lambda you could join the tables like this:

Your data

```
using (var context = new CADWEntities())
        {
              var ownerCheck = context.LinkAnalysis.Join(context.Subjects
                                                   x => x.LinkId,
                                                   y => y.LinkId,
                                                   (x, y) => new {Analysis = x, Subjects = y})
                                              .Where(join => join.Analysis.LinkAnalysisCreator == dbUser)
                                              .Where(join => join.Subjects.Subjects == SubjectID);

            totalRowCount = ownercheck.Count();
            if (totalRowCount == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Example data with live example

```
    var query = linkAnalysisList.Join(subjectList,
                                     x => x.LinkId,
                                     y => y.LinkId,
                                     (x, y) => new {Analysis = x, Subjects = y})
        .Where(a => a.Analysis.LinkAnalysisCreator == "Perry")
        .Where(a => a.Subjects.SubjectId == 50);
```

Considering you want to join it by LinkId?

Here is a live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EzPCBu

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your suggestions and example.  After looking over your work I was able to get my solution working using the code below.  You can see I used several of your examples and suggestion to get it working.

```
public Boolean EditSubject(int LinkID, int SubjectID, string dbUser )
    {


        int totalRowCount;


        using (var context = new CADWEntities())
        {
            //string dbuser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var q = (from l in context.LinkAnalysis
                     join s in context.Subjects on l.LinkAnalysisId equals s.LinkAnalysisId
                     orderby s.LinkAnalysisId
                     where l.LinkAnalysisCreator == dbUser && s.SubjectId == SubjectID
                     select 0);
            totalRowCount = q.Count();
            if (totalRowCount == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
       }
    }
```

Thanks again for your help